# Get value from appended child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main react component which appends child components say `<Child />` on button click

My `Child` component is of the format

```
<form>
    <input .... />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

Now I need to get the value of these `input` elements from every `Child` component which is appended but am not able to figure out a way to do so.

I won't know how many `Child` components would be added as the user can click the button any number of times to append yet another `<Child />` so I can't have a fixed number of variables exported from the Child component to a variable in parent component.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Code to append the child:

- The `submit` function:

```js
const [val, setVal] = useState([]);

const submit = () => {
    setVal([...val, <Child />]);
}
```

- Append button:

```
<Button onClick={submit}>Add Child</Button>
```

- To render:

```
{val}
```

Since `val` is an array, it prints all the components inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took some liberties because I don't know what would be the expected output of all the forms.

What I basically did is to create a map-like structure where I will map each child form with its value/s (depending on your needs could be modified) and I passed a `submit` function to the child components in order to store the values on the parent.

In that way on a child submit I will be able to get the values passed from the child as well as its index.

**Parent component**

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState([]);
  // Map like structure to store the values (is just an example, you can use whatever you want)
  const [mapOfValues, setMapOfValues] = useState({});

  // Pass submit function as prop
  const submit = () => {
    setVal([...val, <Child submit={onChildSubmit} />]);
  };

  // Submit function that stores the value for the child
  const onChildSubmit = (childIndex, value) => {
    setMapOfValues({
      ...mapOfValues,
      [childIndex]: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {val.map((value, index) =>
        // Key to prevent React warning and childIndex to map the value to the child form
        React.cloneElement(value, { key: index, childIndex: index })
      )}
      <button onClick={submit}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child component**

```js
const Child = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.submit(props.childIndex, value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
      <input onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Once you are done, and you want to submit from the parent component, you could use a `reduce`, `map` or whatever you need to format the values as you want.

The link to the sandbox is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-diffie-km0r0?file=/src/App.js)

If you have any other question let me know.

Comment: Damn this worked like a charm
Also, if I'm not wrong, the `Child` is directly accessing the parent function `onChildSubmit` through prop right? I didn't know we could pass functions as props too, that was really great

Comment: @luckongas I tried to implement `onChildDelete` too like `onChildSubmit`. I was able to make it work for `mapOfValues` using `delete` with a temporary variable; but am not able to do the same for `val`. I tried using `const tempField = educationFields.splice(childIndex, 1);
        setEducationFields(tempField)` but that empties my whole array if I try to delete the first element. Instead of just removing the first element. It would be great if you could suggest a way for this